# SSL Cert error after migrating to hosted exchange service

Tags: email, ssl, exchange, microsoft-office-365

**OLD SETUP**
SBS 2011 w/ Exchange and all clients running Office 2010 (using rpc/http as many were laptops)

**NEW SETUP**
All mailboxes and accounts moved to hosted Exchange.  Local Exchange services stopped.  New profiles created with new hosted Exchange settings.

**PROBLEM**
The local SSL cert expired last week and the clients for some reason are getting SSL cert expiration warnings when launching Outlook.  I've checked the server settings and also Outlook connections (right click Outlook icon in system tray and choose Connections) and I see no references to the local Exchange server.

I've checked DNS - no zone for the domain.  They used to use mail.company.com as the old reference (SSL cert for this DNS name) which was nat'd to the exchange server.  They've since changed the A record for mail.company.com to a CNAME record which points to the hosted exchange service.

I can't figure out why Outlook is still looking at the internal server.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that your clients are retrieving the internal autodiscover connection point from your old exchange server using the AD SCP and connecting to on-premises IIS exchange autodiscover virtual directory.

What does `Get-ClientAccessServer | fl AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri` get you?  You'll probably want to `Set-ClientAccessServer -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri $nul`

See also MSDN How to: Find Autodisover endpoints by using SCP lookup in Exchange:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn467395%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am unable to perform powershell commands as all Exchange services have been stopped.

Comment: Well start them up again and run the commands.  It shouldn't be necessary to shut down the exchange services to make the migration work.